# How to subset PolySet data in PBSmapping package?

Tags: r

This is a repost from **gis.stackexchange**. The question is [fairly long and detailed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/how-to-select-a-subset-of-polyset-data-in-r), so I am not repeating it. The simple problem is that I can't figure out a way of subsetting `PolySet` data used in the `PBSmapping` package. One option would be to convert to `SpatialPolygons` with **maptools**, subset it, and the convert back to `PolySet`, but obviously this is just a workaround. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for attr:

```
df[attr(df, "PolyData")$NAME_1 == 'Bumthang',]
```

EDIT:

Would this work?

The argument `col` stands for color and is linked to the PID value.

```
df$Z='white'
df[attr(df, "PolyData")$NAME_1 == 'Bumthang',]$Z ="red"

plotPolys(df,col=df$Z)
```

[image]

You can also play around with the arg `border` that gives the color of the borders.
If you put it "white" then the only region showing will be Bumthang.

Something like this would work:

```
df$W = 'white'
#borders of the region
df[attr(df, "PolyData")$NAME_1 == 'Bumthang',]$W ="red"
plotPolys(df,col=df$Z,border=df$W)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry this is not working. But I don't understand why. Running attr(df, "PolyData")$NAME_1 does indeed give me the list of values of NAME_1 (including 'Bumthang')!

Comment: What is exactly what you are trying to achieve? is not so clear to me; Is it something in a map? could you draw an example? or show a little example?

Comment: The PolySet data has many subregions. So if you do plotPolys(df), it draws the entire map, with all the sub-regions. I want to subset out a particular sub-region, and then plot it: plotPolys(sub_df) or plotLines(sub_df).

Comment: I am curious about this. @user702432 did you find any other solution?

Comment: Nope! I myself am surprised. One workaround I am using is the PolySet2SpatialPolygons() function in the maptools library and then subseting the SpatialPolygons data. But my system is choking on large datasets ('00+ mbs). But thanks for your tip, AndresT. I must have missed this in my mailbox. I'm marking it as the solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a using another library to subset the file? You could subset the data using rgdal, save to file, import the shapefile containing the subset and plot it using PBSMapping.

```
library(rgdal)
library(PBSmapping)

df <-  readOGR(".","df")
subset <- df[df$NAME_1=="Bumthang",]
writeOGR(subset, ".", "bumthang", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
bum = importShapefile("bumthang.shp")
plotPolys(bum, projection=TRUE)
```

[image]

Or you could do away with PBSmapping altogether.

```
 plot(subset, axes=TRUE)
```

[image]